# throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback');

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

So I am learning about node.js and facebook authentication, and I ran into this error:

```html
/home/lindan4/Git/HelloNodeJS/ChatTime/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:79
  if (!verify) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback'); }
                 ^

TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a verify callback
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/home/lindan4/Git/HelloNodeJS/ChatTime/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:79:24)
    at new Strategy (/home/lindan4/Git/HelloNodeJS/ChatTime/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/strategy.js:55:18)
    at module.exports (/home/lindan4/Git/HelloNodeJS/ChatTime/app/auth/index.js:42:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lindan4/Git/HelloNodeJS/ChatTime/server.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:308:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:878:3)
```

Here's the code:

```html
'use strict';

const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('../config');
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

const helper = require('../helpers');

module.exports = () => {

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });


  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    helper.findById(id).then(user => {
      done(null, user);
    }).catch('Error deserializing user');
  });

  //Issue is here
  let authProcessor = (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      //Find a user in the local MongoDB instance using the profile.id


      helper.findRecord(profile.id).then(result => {
        if (result)
        {
          done(null, result);
        }
        else
        {
            //Create a new user and return
            helper.createNewUser(profile).then(newChatUser => {
              done(null, newChatUser)
            }).catch(error => console.log('Error when creating new user'));
        }
      });
  }

  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(config.fb), authProcessor);
}
```

The error lies in this line:

```
 passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(config.fb), authProcessor);
```

I have looked on google and Stack Overflow and have yet to find a solution. I was hoping that someone could perhaps assist me. For your reference, the "config" module is implemented as shown below:

```html
'use strict';

const devEnv = require('./development.json');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
{
  //Offer production stage environment variables
  module.exports =
  {
    host: process.env.host || "",
    dbURI: process.env.dbURI,
    sessionSecret: process.env.sessionSecret,
    fb: {
      clientID: process.env.fbClientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.fbClientSecret,
      callbackURL: process.env.host + "auth/facebook/callback",
      profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos']
    }
  }
}
else
{
  //Offer dev stage and data
  module.exports = {
    host: devEnv.host,
    dbURI: devEnv.dbURI,
    sessionSecret: devEnv.sessionSecret
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You are calling it like:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({}), function(){} )
```

but it should be:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy( {}, function(){} ) ) //Note where I moved the parenthesis
```

`FacebookStrategy` takes 2 arguments, the first is the object with the id/secret/url, and the 2nd is the function, and `new FacebookStrategy` is the only thing you pass into `passportjs.use()`.

Comment: Thank you sir!! I hope all is well with you and your family.

Answer (score 0):

As per the passport.js docs , while configuring the facebook strategy ,function                               `passport.use()` in which the second parameter which is a function should `return the callback function` which you have not returned.

Answer (score 0):

In my case mistakenly I've used  **GoogleStrategy.Strategy();** instead of  **GoogleStrategy.Strategy;**
that was my error
so consider if you got the same error

Answer (score 0):

In `.env` or `keys.js` if both name is same like:

```
ClientID: keys.google.ClientID
```

Then, you need to change of of the first letter in lowercase like:

```
clientID: keys.google.ClientID
```

Now it will work fine.